# e.pageY returns 0 once click a drop down in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Even though I click a drop down in the middle of the page this  value returns 0 for Google chrome. What may be the issue? This is correctly working with FF and IE

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
   var yPos = e.pageY;
});
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sQmXz/ I can confirm this (Chrome, Ubuntu), but I get -436 instead of 0 (has to do with the iframe used on jsfiddle).

Comment: I think this classifies as a possible bug that you should report, see here how to submit it: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: I tried the exact script in chrome in ubuntu. For me it gives 0 once i click drop down.

Comment: The value itself is not that important. What is important is that it a) changes and b) freezes while the dropdown is active. I can't see a logical reason for this behavior, and since other browser behave more the way you'd expect it, it should be filed as a bug report.